# how to style a button using pixate (android)

Tags: android, css, button, pixate

I am new to using pixate so I am sorry if my question sounds naive

I want to style a button ,I have created an Activity and added css in my assets folder but still there is no change in the button.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Pixate.init(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Pixate.setStyle(b, "button.css");
}
```

button.css

```
#button1 {
background-color: linear-gradient(#FF679B,#394170);
height: 44px;
border-radius  : 5px;
border-width   : 1px;
border-color   : #444;
}
```

Comment: go here http://www.pixate.com/blog/2013-10-30-android-button-demo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your styling in a `default.css` file under your assets (any other file name will not load). After that, you are pretty much set without calling the `setStyle` (you don't need that in that context).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Pixate.init(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // No need to get a hold of the button. Pixate init will capture it.
    // Just make sure you have set the id in the XML layout to "button1"
    // Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
}
```

[ADDITION]
Also note the comment above and check out the blog post at http://www.pixate.com/blog/2013-10-30-android-button-demo/ to see how to style the button's states.
Pixate is an open-source project, so you can grab the library from https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-android (it contains a couple of sample projects to help you get started)

Comment: I have renamed the button.css file to default.css and removed the setstyle statement its still not working

Comment: Ok, I created a project for you, and it's working as expected. You can grab the zip from https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfu3m9glhm0q58g/PixateButtonTest.zip 
Also, looks like you are using an older version. There is no such class `Pixate` anymore. It was replaced by `PixateFreestyle`. You can grab the latest from the github repo link I've posted above. Then import it as a project to your workspace and adjust the library path in the project I linked here.

Comment: I have one more doubt, Instead of adding each button in css is there any way to use single style in all the buttons.

Comment: Yes. Just do: `Button { ... }` instead of the `#btID { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you it saved a lot of my time

Comment: great!
Btw, a small typo on the previous comment. Should be lowercase button: `button { ... }`.